# Augment imported module declaration

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've installed both `webpack-bundle-analyzer` and `@types/webpack-bundle-analyzer` in my project and I can say that provided declarations are working correctly, however, those declarations are not complete. Besides `BundleAnalyzerPlugin` class, the library also exports the `start()` function.

**How do I augment the existing declaration to add `start()` function to it?**

I've tried creating the following file: `./types/webpack-bundle-analyzer/index.d.ts` with the following content:

```typescript
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';

declare module 'webpack-bundle-analyzer' {

  export function start(
    bundleStats: any,
    opts: BundleAnalyzerPlugin.Options
  );

}
```

But it doesn't change anything for some reason.

My `tsconfig.json` has `typeRoots` option set:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/",
      "types/"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
src/somefile.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/@types/webpack-bundle-analyzer"' has no exported member 'start'.

4 import { start } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';
```

Original declaration is defined like this:

```typescript
import { Plugin, Compiler } from 'webpack';

export namespace BundleAnalyzerPlugin {
    interface Options { … }
}

export class BundleAnalyzerPlugin extends Plugin {
    constructor(options?: BundleAnalyzerPlugin.Options);
    apply(compiler: Compiler): void;
}
```

Comment: Module augmentation should be included as regular file/module

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the way my `tsconfig.json` was written:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/",
      "types/"
    ]
  }
}
```

I needed to change the order of search directories, so that my local declarations took precedence over the ones imported from `node_modules`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "types/",
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The whole day I spent trying to understand why type augmentation is not working in my project. This feature really needs to be better documented. Anyway thanks for the answer, absolute life saver.